# jQuery plugin to re-order blocks to save space?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

So the thing is I have some blocks in my site (floating divs) which I want to be able to re-order, to make them take less space.
Each of my blocks' width is either x, 2x, or 3x (x is a number). Their width will never change, but their height can change.
I know I can create some JavaScript code to do handle this, but since I'm already using jQuery and I know about the large amount of jQuery plugins out there, I came here first to ask if there is already a plugin which does this, in order to save some time.

Comment: If it is images http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-tiles-gallery/2281417 might work for you. It is also possible to replace images with other contents. But, as Patrick asks, what do you mean by "take less space"? Note that if you have elements that only change height, you might want to look at Isotope's http://isotope.metafizzy.co/custom-layout-modes/masonry-column-shift.html functionality which you might tweak for your (not clear) purpose. What have you tried? Got a jsfiddle of it?

Comment: Save space meaning that their container has a fixed width, and that their height should be as low as possible

Comment: Well, from all I know and see, Tiles Gallery or Isotope Masonry Column Shift could manage that.

Answer (score 3):

Masonry plugin for jquery http://masonry.desandro.com/ or even better the Isotope http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: +1, Those are pretty cool actually... did not know about such things.

Comment: Wow, I actually knew about Isotope and I can't believe I didn't think about it, anyway I'll check them.

Comment: Okay, so after some testing I found out that there is a problem with both of the plugins, they both don't really re-order the blocks, all they do is placing them in a way that saves the most space, while I want the plugin to completely re-order them to save as much space as possible.